# C++, dynamic_cast и уточнение интерфейса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования, интерфейс, dynamic-cast

Я уже долго пытаюсь придумать, как можно организовать игровую механику классического `Worms`. Мне удалось найти разные варианты, но все они со своими *клопами* и абсолютно мне не нравятся. Чувствую, что существует удобное решение, но никак не могу его нащупать, поэтому - прошу помощи.

Итак, рассмотрим уровень классического `Worms`, он содержит:

- Разрушаемую землю, которая к тому же используется для коллизий. Этот вопрос я решил;
- Баллистические объекты. Будем считать, что все, кроме взрывов, является баллистикой и может взаимодействовать друг с другом и ландшафтом. Например, граната толкает червя. В классическом `Worms` не так, но так интереснее;
- Взрывы. Разрушают ландшафт, толкают всю баллистику.

Для упрощения будем считать, что у юнитов нет здоровья.

В общем-то, это основное. Самое интересное заключается в том, что юниты могут обладать некоторыми особыми свойствами. Например, они могут иметь здоровье, они могут активироваться червем и т.д.

Для упрощения представим, что у нас есть только одно специальное свойство:

- Активируется червем;

Чтобы не строить очередную `Звезду Смерти`, я подумал, что можно сделать примерно такое наследование:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Взаимодействие объектов строится через:

```
virtual void Unit::interact(Unit *_object);
```

Наследники дополняют поведение своих потомков, все объекты валяются в одном месте, каждый объект сам решает, что он умеет делать и как влиять на другие объекты.

Но есть проблемы.

`void Ballistic::interact(Unit *_object)` должен проверять, относится ли `_object` ко классу `Ballistic`.

`void ActivatedByWorm::interact(Unit *_object)` должен проверять, относится ли `_object` ко классу `Worm`.

И если для `ActivatedByWorm` это еще было позволительно, потому что объектов типа `ActivatedByWorm` немного, то при учете взрывов придется делать постоянные проверки при просчете баллистики. А если еще учитывать и то, что взрывы могут наносить урон тому, у чего есть здоровье... То понижающее приведение появляется во все больших и больших классах.

Поэтому, мои вопросы такие:

1. Является ли понижающее приведение при помощи `dynamic_cast` хорошим способом проверить у объекта наличие определенного интерфейса?
2. Как еще можно построить взаимодействие между объектами в моем случае? Я перепробовал кучу паттернов, и удобного способа реализации задуманного не нашел. Самое удобное и чистое - использовать `dynamic_cast`, но у меня есть сомнения, что это <s>православный</s> приемлемый способ.

Comment: 1. нет. 2. избавиться от бесполезной иерархии классов

Comment: @VTT, чем ее заменить?

Comment: Пачкой отдельных типов, в которых например баллистические свойства отделены от игровых.

Comment: @VTT, можно посмотреть на минимальный пример того, что именно вы имеете в виду?

Comment: хотя бы тот же box2d

Comment: @VTT, смотрел. Допустим, таким образом я смогу организовать баллистику. Баллистические объекты будут взаимодействовать друг с другом. Но ведь помимо баллистики есть еще много чего, что трудно классифицировать в отдельности от остального.

Comment: Может быть, однако имеет смысл не пытаться пихать все в одну большую иерархию. Разбивка должна быть хотя бы по подсистемам.